# How to add put jquery in a javascript document without messing up the javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, runtime-error

I realize that jquery is just a dictionary of javascript functions, but in my javascript/html5 document, when I change the script tag to `script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"` or any of the other jQuery reference tags, it makes my canvas disappear (it doesn't give an error on inspect element though and some buttons I made stay)
Do you know either
1.how to stop the jquery from messing up my code or
2. how i can alternate use of jQuery and non-jQuery javascript in a program?

Comment: This is because of the conflict

Comment: try using no conflict https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: How about learning how to debug so you can actually fix the problem. Start by opening the browser console and look for errors.